# App engine Python NDB map_async using callback, objects and inheritance pattern

Tags: python, google-app-engine, inheritance, callback, app-engine-ndb

I have a Parser class which has methods to parse docs. Parser is like a "container" of parser functions. Now Parser also encloses a NDB map_async callback to pass additional arguments to the callback.

Class P has an instance for every mapped doc entity, which uses the single Parser instance to parse a doc.

```
class P (object):

    def __init__(self, parser, ...):
        self.parser = parser
        ....

    def get_content(...)
        ....             # using methods from P and self.parser 

    def other methods ...
        ....             # using methods from P and self.parser

class Parser(object):

    def __init__(args)
        ....

    def some parser methods()
        ....

    def callback(entity):   # Is now a method of Parser, but ....

        p = P(self, ...)
        ....
        content = p.get_content(...)
        ....

parser = Parser(...)   # initialize Parser (instance, closure)
query = Docs.query()
multi_future = query.map_async(parser.callback)
....    # process results
```

This works fine, but does not feel well structured.

I look for a solution where P inherits from Parser:
(The callback can / should be part of P)

```
query = Docs.query()
multi_future = query.map_async(????? P ??????)
....    # process results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, using a lambda.

```
query = Docs.query()
multi_future = query.map_async(lambda entity: P(...).callback(entity))
```